# Group received messages in RabbitMQ, preferably using Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm receiving messages from a service (S) that publishes each individual property change to an entity as a separate message. A contrived example would be an entity like this:

```
Person {
    id: 123
    name: "Something",
    address: {...}
}
```

If name and address are updated in the same transaction then (S) will publish two messages, `PersonNameCorrected` and `PersonMoved`. The problem is on the receiving side where I'm storing a projection of this `Person` entity and each property change causes a write to the database. So in this example there would be two writes to the database but if I could batch messages for a short period of time and group them by id then I would only have to make a single write to the database.

How does one typically handle this in RabbitMQ? Does Spring AMQP provide an easier abstraction?

Note that I have looked briefly at [prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Also prefetch, if I understand it correctly, is per connection basis. I'm trying to achieve this on a *per-queue* basis, because if batching (and thus added latency) is the way to go I wouldn't like to add this latency to ALL queues consumed by my service (but only to those that need the "group-by-id" features).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefetch won't help for a case like this.

Consider using [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) which has adapters that sit on top of Spring AMQP; it also provides an aggregrator which can be used to group messages together before sending them on to the next stage in the pipeline.

**EDIT**

Here's a quick boot app to demostrate...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42969130Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So42969130Application.class, args)
            .close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.template.convertAndSend("so9130", new PersonNameChanged(123));
        this.template.convertAndSend("so9130", new PersonMoved(123));
        this.handler.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "so9130")
                        .messageConverter(converter()))
                .aggregate(a -> a
                        .correlationExpression("payload.id")
                        .releaseExpression("false") // open-ended release, timeout only
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        .groupTimeout(2000))
                .handle(handler())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Handler handler() {
        return new Handler();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so9130", false, false, true);
    }

    public static class Handler {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handle(Collection<?> aggregatedData) {
            System.out.println(aggregatedData);
            this.latch.countDown();
        }

    }

    public static class PersonNameChanged {

        private int id;

        PersonNameChanged() {
        }

        PersonNameChanged(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PersonNameChanged [id=" + this.id + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class PersonMoved {

        private int id;

        PersonMoved() {
        }

        PersonMoved(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "PersonMoved [id=" + this.id + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so42969130</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>so42969130</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Result:

```
2017-03-23 09:56:57.501  INFO 75217 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.a.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler : 
    Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[123]
[PersonNameChanged [id=123], PersonMoved [id=123]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to spring integration. If it's not too much to ask, would you happen to know of an example that I could use as a kick-starter for my use case?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example which should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I know that I should be brief on SO but must say that this is great, I couldn't have asked for a better answer, so thanks :).

Answer (score -1):

This is just plainly wrong to shift shortcoming of messaging system to software/service-side using Spring-Integration It is also not a case for Spring Integration nor any framework. It also does not scale well & is not fault-tolerant

The core of this issue is to separate routing messages from business logic/sending messages

AFAIK only Kafka & Apache Artemis support JMSXGroup from JMS API looking at currently mature queue providers RabbitMQ does not have it but AMQP has is specified BUT again RabbitMq haven't ever implemented it despite of requests from community.

That single but also a very often and important case in enterprise architecture to ensure ordered sequential processing from many independent sources excludes RabbitMQ from further considerations as default messaging solution