# RabbitMQ workaround for JMSXGroupId

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I know RabbitMQ does not support JMSXGroupId, and from the [link](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/262), it seems no sooner this feature going to be incorporated to RabbitMQ. Is there any work around for that say using combination of exchanges/queues/topics? Here is my use case.

Say I've 1 Producer Server and 2 consumer servers with multiple consumer threads consuming from the queue. The Producer Server creates a network and a subnet and multiple ports. All these request is converted json/stomp and put into a Queue. Now How can I guarantee that same thread processes all these request that belongs to same network. In ActiveMQ "Classic" or ActiveMQ Artemis we can set JMSXGroupId as network name and ensure that messages are picked up by same thread/ensure there is ordering of the message belonging to same group that is network. How can I achieve this in RabbitMQ?

Second part if the above is possible (I'm bit greedy), is it also possible say, I've enabled route_key and create different queue for network/port/subnet or fanout and ensure messages belonging to different are released for consumption in the order based on message group.

I see there is workaround in the client side using spring-integration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969130/group-received-messages-in-rabbitmq-preferably-using-spring-amqp), but Its at client side not in rabbitmq-server itself. Hence, I am not sure how it will ensure transaction and atomicity in HA (active-active mode) are handled in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after going through your question again, it seems like you are publishing different messages when you create a network, subnet and ports. All create separate message and are published. Now it seems like you have multiple consumer, and hence one consumer might consume message that created network and other consumer might consume message that created subnet or port.

To handle this scenario, you basically publish the message to the exchange, and the exchange routes the message to particular queue.

Now if you have unique independant queue that are subscribed at the consumer end, you can tackle the above problem.

```
Producer -> Exchange -> Queue1 -> Consumer1
Producer -> Exchange -> Queue2 -> Consumer2
```

Comment: The problem is not about categorization problem and I understand the routing_key, if you set routing_key as networkname, then foreach new network I need to create that many queues, to group network , subnet, ports belonging to same network name, routing key can applied to in this case If I want to send all network to same queue. and regarding the consumer side part the solution provided in spring-integration does message grouping but at client side. which I'm not looking at. Not sure considered multiple consumer server scenarios.

Comment: still does not resolve the problem, it still address categorization problem. let use say send all the network json to queue1 and pick using consumer1 and subnet json to queue2 and pick using consumer2 then How can we be sure network json is processed before subnet that belongs to same network.